# Removing text-indent when first child element is strong

Tags: html, css

I have a problem thats kinda driving me nuts. I have an article container and within are several paragraphs. The first paragraph contains a drop cap. This **first** paragraph does not use text-indent, however every **following** paragraph does.

When I begin a new paragraph **following** a h3-header, I don't want any text-indent. Fine, I can get this to work (blue text in example).

My problem is this, when I begin a new paragraph with a header (strong followed by a break), this line will use the text-indent of the paragraph, and I **don't** want it to. I must have the strong tags inside the paragraph (as one should), not outside.

I'm thinking of a way to select all paragraphs that start with a strong tag. I **don't** want to use any javascript to solve this. **I want to change the text-indent of the paragraph, not the position of the strong text**.

I've made a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J5C86/1/) here. I have tried something like this:

```
p>strong {
    color:#f0f;
    text-indent: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `<p><strong>` over `<h4>`? I've updated your example to use `<h4>` instead, just in case you had overlooked it: http://jsfiddle.net/J5C86/5/

Comment: I would do that myself, but I would like to make sure that it looks correct if strong is used instead. It is for a Wordpress site and someone else will be adding content. Ive just noticed that many people add sub headers like this.

Comment: As a quick aside to the rest of the answers, the reason your example doesn't work is that `text-indent` isn't valid on inline elements.

Comment: Another reason to use `<h4>` here is that the first word or line of a paragraph may intentionally be bold and the user may not want this turning into a header.

Comment: Hmm, I didn't really consider that. Yes, that's true. I think I'll have to go with the `<h3>` and `<h4>` followed by a paragraph. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a negative margin to the `strong` tag, though I assume you'll want a specific class on it.

```
strong.subhead {
    margin-left: -3em;
}
```

Working example at: http://jsfiddle.net/J5C86/2/

However, this is also assuming you don't want the paragraph associated with the strong tag indented. If you're looking for the paragraph under the subheading to be indented as well, you'll need another tag on the first word or letter after the `br`.

```
span.subhead-indent {
    margin-left: 3em;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/J5C86/4/

Comment: This requires that you give the strong sub header a certain class, which I would like to avoid. If it cannot be done automatically, I would rather remove the text indent all together.

Comment: Sadly, I don't think you're going to find a solution that doesn't require either javascript or specific classes.

Comment: I think you're right. I'll have to consider using jQuery to solve this. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on my comment on your question:

If there's a reason you can't use `<h4>` - which would be the more suitable tag here - you can simply add a negative margin to your `<strong>` element:

```
p > strong:first-child {
    margin-left:-3em;
}
```

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/J5C86/7/).

Otherwise, use `<h4>` instead:

```
<h4>Strong sub header</h4>
<p>Aliquam semper placerat urna...</p>

h3+p, h4+p {
    text-indent:0;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding-top: 0;
}

h3+p {
    color:#00f;
}
```

[JSFiddle example with `<h4>`](http://jsfiddle.net/J5C86/5/).

Comment: Yes, but if some other text within the paragraph is bold, this will be moved as well, like here: http://jsfiddle.net/J5C86/8/

Comment: I think you'll want a specific class rather than `p > strong` or even `p > strong:first-child`. In either case, it could cause issues if there is a strong tag in the paragraph that isn't the subheader or if a subheader isn't present but another strong tag is.

Comment: @ChristofferHald: I may be wrong but I don't believe there is a way to specifically select the very first element. You can use `:first-line` to ensure it's only on the very first line, but this is really why using `<h4>` would be a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me. Use this:

```
p>strong {
  text-indent: 0 !important;
  color: #f0f;
  display: block;
}
```

After doing this, Remove the br tag at the last of p>strong.

Comment: This will fail when there are multiple `strong` tags in the paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/J5C86/9/)**
I saw your problem and found that you have not included your paragraph within the `h3` tag, so define your css with your strong paragraph with a class for eg.

```
<p class="no-indent"><strong>Strong Sub Header</strong></p>
```

define your css this must work.

Comment: `<strong>` has not been removed from HTML5: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-strong-element